# CI 2.1.2 controller in sub directory clean url does not work - tried all the solutions in all the posts I found

Tags: codeigniter, routes, clean-urls

I know this question has been asked many times, I went through a few solutions in the last 2 days and nothing helps.

Please, can someone help?

Using `CI 2.1.2` I have this folder structure:
`appcliaction/controllers/admin/book.php`

`public_html/assets`

In `public_html` I have this in my `index.php` file:

```
$application_folder = '../application';
```

In my routes.php file I have this:

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/book';
```

In my **config** file:

```
$config['index_page'] ='';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';//I tried all the options here
```

My **htaccess** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

My book **controller** extends an `Admin_Controller` from the libraries folder.

The `Admin_Controller`:

```
function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['meta_title'] = 'ThinklocalCMS';
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');

    // Login check
    $exception_uris = array(
        'auth/login', 
        'auth/logout'
    );
    if (in_array(uri_string(), $exception_uris) == FALSE)
    {
        if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
            redirect('auth/login');
        else
            $this->data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    }
}
```

Going to `mysite.co.za/admin` I get `Page Not Found` (Of course, this is working fine on my local machine).

Going to `mysite.co.za/admin/book`
I get the `ion_auth` login screen which is what should happen.

Please, can someone help? I really tried finding the solution with all the posts that I found on google.

Comment: Try add this to your `routes.php` `$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';` I don't really understand the question what you are trying to achieve. Does everything work on localhost? Problem occur only on hosting?

Comment: Hi Kyslik, What I am trying to do is go to mysite/admin and get the login page or the admin page if the user is logged in and is an admin. Everything works fine on my local machine. I go to mysite/admin and I get the login screen. On the live server, going to mysite/admin gives me page not found. If I put mysite/admin I want it to go to the controller: application/controllers/admin/book.php - on the live server, it doesn't, page not found on the local server it does - gives me the login screen. I don't want to have to put admin/book in my url just admin

Comment: OH MY GOD !!! Found the solution, my public_html had an old admin folder in it, that cause all the problems. Thank you

Comment: Is live server running `mod_rewrite`?  **//edit** : ok glad to help :D